# How do I initialize webcams without signing in to an X session?

Tags: ssh, webcam

I'm attempting to use OpenCV for a robotics project, and I'd like to be able to capture from the webcam without having to log in to an X session on the host. Currently I have to sign in through the GUI login screen before any webcam will respond. For example, when I am using ssh with X forwarding and start cheese, it will say "No device found," until I sign in on the host at which point launching cheese will stream the video as expected.

I'm relatively inexperienced in Linux and I'm hoping there's some kind of startup script I can create that will initialize the webcam without logging in.

Comment: You can post your answer separately, and even accept it so that other can see that your question has an answer

Comment: Yeah it told me I had to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to start the webcam remotely by using sudo. Not sure why that was required but it's good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is uvc subsystem for this and `uvcviewer` application. Unfortunately, it does not support all webcams. [Here is the link](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/).

Comment: I just looked into that and was a bit confused, but I did manage to find [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UVC) and install guvcview, which does appear to work with my webcam. It has some interesting settings but unfortunately has the same problem of not seeing that there is a webcam attached until I log in on the host. Is there some kind of manual somewhere that might have the command to initialize without log in?

Comment: I used it to snap pictures from webcam on Debian, from root console, without X even installed. Didn't use it any other way.